# R dplyr filter function remove every other row

Tags: r, dplyr

I am applying the `R dplyr::filter` function to the `nycflights13` flights dataset.
I am trying to select only flights in November and December, using two alternatives scripts.

```
library (tidyverse) 
library (nycflights13)
```

**1**
`df1 <- filter (flights, month == 11 | month == 12)`

**2**
`df2 <- filter (flights, month == c(11,12))`

**df1** yields the expected result (with 55403 total observations) and **df2** does too but with the dataset only contains half of the observations (27702 in total). **df2** has every other row removed.

My question is: does anyone know why? I know the **df2** syntax is incorrect, but I am trying to understand why it yields the outcome that it does.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: does anyone know why?

R recycles vectors when they're not long enough for the whatever it is you need them for.  In the df2 syntax the `filter` will filter for month = 11 in row 1, month = 12 in row 2, month = 11 in row 3...

You should end up with flights from November that were from odd rows of the original data & flights from December that were from even numbered rows of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
df2 <- filter (flights, month %in% c(11,12))
```

Your code when using `==` can be considering only the first element of the vector. Also, the `|` operator looks like is evaluating each condition separatedly whereas `==` is evaluating the condition simultaneously.

Comment: I tend to agree with your response. But it still doesn't explain why it cuts off every other row.

Comment: @frankieR It looks like it first looks for the two values and then cut to half of data. You can run `table(df1$month)` and `table(df2$month)` and see how data is reduced to half when using `==`

Comment: I get it now. Thanks @Duck

Comment: @frankieR Always a pleasure helping you!

Answer (score 0):

In agree with @Duck about the difference between using `|` and `==`

But this does not explain yet why R cuts off every other row.

I also ran two separate commands below filtering only the flights in Dec or Nov, respectively. And the average of the observations across the 2 (28135 and 27268) is the same as the # of observations in `df2` (27702)

`df3 <- filter (flights, month == 11)`

`df4 <- filter (flights, month == 12)`